# VisualStudio.com URL to latest release build of a project

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am new to visualstudio.com and is mostly using it for version control (moving from Github). 
One of the projects there is a console app to perform some maintenance on our local servers. 
There is a build job producing an ‘Artifact’, which seems to contain everything the server needs to perform its maintenance job (scheduled by Jenkins).

Now, it would be really cool if the Jenkins job on our local server, could start by “downloading” the latest released version of the console app from VisualStudio.com, and then run the console app.

The thing I don’t understand is how to go from a successful (Release) build to a URL where the binaries can be downloaded (regardless of version number - always latest).

It may involve a “publish” task, but opening a file share on local server, to push the result, is not the way I want to go. I want the local server to pull the app from VisualStudio.com when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can build your project directly by jenkins job through MSBuild CLI, it can also generate the build artifacts similar as the build process in VSTS build.

Besides, if you want to **download the VSTS build artifacts in Jenkins job**, you can can the build artifacts download URL first through [Get build artifacts REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-build-artifacts):

```
GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildID}/artifacts?api-version=2.0
```

Then you will get the response like:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "drop",
      "resource": {
        "type": "Container",
        "data": "#/303511/drop",
        "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/build/builds/391/artifacts/drop",
        "downloadUrl": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/build/builds/391/artifacts/drop?%24format=zip"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For the above example, the download URL is `https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/build/builds/391/artifacts/drop?%24format=zip`.

---

To get the latest build id, you can use the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#for-a-build-definition) to get the latest build firstly:

```
GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitionID}&$top=1&api-version=2.0
```

Then you can get the latest buildID in the id parameter.

Comment: The {buildID} in the "Get build artifacts REST API" URL, makes me think the answer is No - there is no URL to the "latest and greatest" (release) build

Comment: Actually you can get the latest buildID by another rest api which I added in the end my my answer. You can have a try.

Comment: I finally got around to testing it, and it works as expected, thank you very much. The definitions parameter I found from looking in the address bar browsing around in the project in visualstudio.com (5 in my case), but what does it mean, and where is it supposed to be found?